# Connection betwen definition of mapping cone of a topological space and of a Complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

*Definition 1*:
Given a Map $f: X \to Y$ between two topological spaces define the *mapping cone* $C_f$ as $(X \times I) \sqcup Y / \tilde{} $ with $(x,0) \tilde{} (x\prime{}, 0)$ and $(x, 1) \tilde{} f(x)$

*Definition 2*: 
Given two Complexes $A: \dots  \to A^{n+1} \to A^n \to A^{n - 1} \to \dots $ and $B: \dots \to B^{n+1} \to B^n \to B^{n-1} \to \dots$ and a map $F: A \to B$ Note the degree shift by $n$ as $A[n]$ and the differentials of each complex by $d_A$ (or $d_B$)  Define the *mapping cone of a complex* as $C_f = A[1] \oplus B $ with differential $ \begin{pmatrix} 
d_{A[1]} & 0 \\ f[1] & d_B\end{pmatrix} $.

I understand both definitions and have some geometric intuition for them.
But I dont understand the connection between them. How is the second definition motivated by the first one?

bg,
Johannes